# Redirect URL which contains "option=com_virtuemart"

Tags: redirect

I want to 301 redirect some URLs which contain "option=com_virtuemart".
I tried with this code:

> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_virtuemart
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

But it doesn't work.

Comment: be helpful to know what webserver it is you are having problems with.

Comment: Apache/2.0.55 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.1.2, but I think the problem is in my code

Answer (score 0):

The code is working, but the server is disabled htaccess controll..